# Finding a reversed words in a given string using C program

Tags: c

Actually I have been searching for more than 1 week to find a solution for finding a reversed words in a given string using C. My question is, I have been given a string like this "bakelovekac". Here I have a reversed word of "ake" as "eka" in a string. Now I need to find out this reversed word in a given string and print it. How can it be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems an ACM or OI problem... What's the range of string length? What's the time limit? If there's no restriction on time, you may just use a stupid brute force; otherwise you need some clever hash trick or dynamic programming I guess.

Comment: There is no time limit

Comment: is ake a word?  is it just any series of characters or does it have to be a real word?

Comment: @Bwebb No it doesn't need to be a real word. Just being a series of characters is enough.

Comment: any limit on the size of the original word?

Comment: Not like that sir!

Comment: Are you given a list of possible words?

Comment: Yes. The input will have atleast one reversed words.

Comment: whats the minimum length requirement for the "word" to be considered the reversed word?  "a" is a word and its trivially reversed in there as the second and second to last letter.  I assume atleast two but thats probably still to short, is it three like in your example?

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach would be to iterate over all the characters of the string and for each character check if it is being repeated, if yes then check for the presence of a possible reverse string.

A crude code for above approach would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void checkForRevWord(char *str, char *rev){
        int length = 0;
        while(1){
                if(str >= rev)
                        break;
                if(*str != *rev)
                        break;
                length++;
                str++;
                rev--;
        }   
        if(length > 1){ 
                while(length--)
                        printf("%c", *(rev+length+1));
                printf("\n");
        }   
        return;
}

int main()
{
        char *inputStr = "bakelovekac";
        char *cur = inputStr;
        char *tmp;

        while(*cur != '\0'){
                tmp = cur+1;
                /* find if current char gets repeated in the input string*/
                while(*tmp != '\0'){
                        if(*tmp == *cur){
                                checkForRevWord(cur, tmp);
                        }   
                        tmp++;
                }   
                cur++;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char text[50]; //this character array to store string
        int len,i;
        printf("Enter a text\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",text);//getting the user input with spaces until the end of the line
        len=strlen(text);//getting the length of the array and assigning it the len variable
        for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            printf("%c",text[i]); //printing the text from backwards
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

thank you.

Comment: This seems to not address the OPs question about finding a sub string inside the string.  I will let him decide though.